# Is 2 stage furnace worth it in dual fuel setup?

Tags: heating, furnace, heat-pump

I am replacing a gas furnace with AC unit with a gas + heat pump system.

Looking at 2 stage furnaces I was left to wonder if its advantages hold in that setup. If gas is only used for temperature below -12°C, will it be always at 100% or would it go to it’s second stage?

Comment: How many BTU does the Gas furnace produces, and how many BTU is needed for your home.

Comment: @knowitall My current furnace has effective 93000 btu. I am waiting for evaluation… except it is definitely enough to keep us confortable on coldest days (<-30°C). I guess it make sense that the more oversized the furnace is, the more it will use the two stages.

Comment: "2 stage equipment is for comfort, not economy." - "I see no benefit to dual stage systems less than ~10 tons. **The second stage is for those months that your first stage can't handle.** In your situation it sounds like it would either always run both or never need the second." [New Central Air Install: choosing single-stage vs dual-stage condensers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41072/new-central-air-install-choosing-single-stage-vs-dual-stage-condensers) *"it is definitely enough to keep us comfortable on coldest days"* ... then you don't need two-stage.

Comment: What you *need* (if you live in Texas) is to get your state hooked to either of the national power grids.

Comment: If it's at all possible for you, I would *seriously* look at Empire/Williams "wall furnace" for emergency heat.  Here's why: **They work with the power out** because they do everything by convection. (that also makes them somewhat less efficient, e.g. they rely on hot exhaust to ventilate).   The units are cheap, $1000 for 50,000 BTU - get two lol.  However, these are culturally not accepted outside the Sun belt - no one stocks them and no one will even admit they exist.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar system. I installed an 8 ton AC/Heat pump many years ago, with variable speed fans etc.I also added the electrostatic filters. I was was told that the only way to go was with electric for backup heat. I opted for a two stage gas furnace, it was expensive. That was the best decisions I could have made. Over the years electricity has gotten extremely expensive. One day I decided to push the Emergency heat button and see what it did. It went to a gas furnace. The combined gas/electric bill went down about >20%, yes gas is much less expensive. It has paid for itself several times over the years. I also paid extra for there stat, that was also a wise decision it works very well. Go with the Aux gas heat you will like it.

Comment: Hard to imagine that electricity is going to do anything but increase in price. We're making more & more demands for electricity, but supply is going up _very_ slowly

Comment: @freeman, on the west coast the supply is going down because multiple (3) coal fired power plants are being closed early, my parents had rolling blackouts last year , some say the rest of the west coast will have them and with the reservoirs at historic lows Vegas may even go dark soon, well start the rolling blackouts like everyone else. I love all the green jobs just increases electricians pay, but we don’t have the power grid to maintain without coal and nuclear or at the level we used to have.